# Pass variable to MULTIPLE functions

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm not sure whether this is a duplicate or not, but I couldn't find a post on this topic..

I'm trying to pass an array object to multiple functions. I know you normally do something like this:

```
function name(values){
    var values ={
        name : "John",
        lastname: "Doe"
    }
    sayHello(values){
        alert(values.name);
    }
}
```

But in this case this isn't working. The array object is passed like the code snippet above, and it works fine. But when I later want to use it in a different function I get the error that the variable isn't defined. This is my code:

```
function createValues(values){
    var values = {left:     (Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)),
                  right:    (Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)),
                  bottom:   (Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)),
                  top:      (Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1))
            };  
    displayValues(values);
}

function displayValues(values){
     document.getElementById("left").innerHTML    = values.left;
     document.getElementById("right").innerHTML   = values.right;
     document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML  = values.bottom;
     document.getElementById("top").innerHTML     = values.top;
     // The values are getting passed to this function
 }

function calcScore(p1_choice, values){
    if(p1_choice == "left"){
        score += values.left
        // Can't access the variables here
    }
}
```

The calcScore function is called by another function after a button has been clicked. I'v tried to make values global, but that didn't help.
I have no idea how to pass the variables to the calcScore function, can anybody help?

Comment: Show how you call `calcScore`.

Comment: When the user click a button `determineChoice` is called, which calls `getCpuChoice(cpuChoice)` and from there `calcScore(p1_choice,cpuChoice, values)` is called

Comment: What error are you getting? The code you gave here looks fine.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined`

Comment: When invoking calcScore the value is not accessible. value is local variable for createvalues. calcscores can't acess it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `calcScore` function to this

```
function calcScore(p1_choice){
    var values = {left:     (document.getElementById("left").innerHTML),
                  right:    (document.getElementById("right").innerHTML),
                  bottom:   (document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML),
                  top:      (document.getElementById("top").innerHTML)
        }; 
    if(p1_choice == "left"){
        score += values.left
        // Can't access the variables here
    }
}
```